# "Эта роль ругательная, и я прошу ее ко мне не применять!"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Знаменитая фраза Шпака из к/ф "Иван Васильевич меняет профессию":

**— Эта роль ругательная, и я прошу ее ко мне не применять!**

Её помнят и используют очень часто. А верна ли она?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вам сказать... Раз в народ пошла, значит уже "верна". К тому же эта фраза целиком есть в булгаковском первоисточнике. Булгаков всегда очень точен к выбору каждого слова.

Так что вопрос можно ставить только о том, насколько фраза сама по себе оправдана семантически. И тут - да, вне контекста фраза сомнительна. Сомнения в сочетаемости. Роль можно играть, иметь (если в пьесе), получить и т. д. Но применять - вряд ли. Однако если прочитать или посмотреть весь отрывок целиком
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A3FiLv94eH0
в контексте все вполне оправдано. Шпак считает, что к нему применили выражение "холоп", которое Зинаида называет "ролью". Т.е. Шпак подменяет выражение "выражение" словом "роль". Для Шпака - вполне объяснимо.

К слову "ругательная" это отношения не имеет. 
Если вопрос (как можно предположить из убранного модератором текста), в нем, то оно сомнений не вызывает. Если найду "первую часть" попробую ответить.

Так, вот нашел исходный вопрос. Наверное там и отвечу по существу, а здесь останется на вопрос, каким он стал.

Comment: -...холоп, да холоп! Что это за слово такое?  -Это он из роли, из роли. Ну, вот, роль такая.  -Эта роль ...   Вы считаете, что в этом контексте  "холоп" = "роль"?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Да, по контексту у Шпака выходлит, что холоп = роль. Иначе трудно объяснить его слова. Но вы же не об это изначально спрашивали?!

Answer (score 0):

...возможно, здесь Булгаков одной фразой подчеркивает пропасть между всеми действующими лицами. Как речь средневекового царя "не склоняется" по-современному, так и речь Бунши, оторванного от нормального человеческого восприятия, "не складывается" из театральных терминов в воспринимаемую фразу.

Это, как если бы проффесиональный педагог из детсада стал бы кричать "хулиганы зрения лишают" (поверхностное знание языка милицейских протоколов) в тюрьме, пытаясь подстроить свой опыт под совершенно незнакомую ситуацию.

Мне кажется, здесь намеренно "неправильно" построенная фраза используется, чтобы подчеркнуть "неправильность" самого Бунши.